# entity linq for top 100 complicated query

Tags: c#, linq

i have the following structure in a table:

```
UniqueId    Type        size       RelatedId 
--------------------------------------------
1           honda        100          1
2           mercedes     200          3
3           mazda        300          4
4           mercedes     150          3
5           merecedes    200          3 
6           ford         180          2
7           mercedes     900          5
```

and so on ....

I want to write  a query to get :

The Top 3 items grouped by ONLY honda or mercedes ordered by their size.

Also, when considering rows for a particular Type, there could be multiple rows which may have the same RelatedId, if thats the case, i want to consider the row which is the max UniqueId for that specific RelatedId.

For eg: in the table below, i have 3 rows with RelatedId = 3 for mercedes type,

```
2           mercedes     200          3
4           mercedes     150          3
5           mercedes     200          3
```

In this case, I want to consider only the row with UniqueId = 5 as that is the latest.
In my result set for group type : "mercedes", i would expect my result set to get :

```
mercedes : 
7           mercedes     900          5
5           merecedes    200          3
```

I was able to write something like this:

```
items.GroupBy( x => x.Type).SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.size)).Take(10).
```

How do i group by so that ONLY honda or mercedes are considered?

Also, this includes rows which could have the same RelatedId...(i want the row which has the highest UniqueId in that case for these rows) how do i change the query to account for this?

My expected final result set:

```
1           honda        100          1
7           mercedes     900          5
5           merecedes    200          3
```

thanks everyone.

Comment: Is the result required to be a grouping or is it just about the items being in order so that each group comes as a sequence?

Comment: not really, as long as i get the list ... thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first thing is add a `Where` to your query to get only Honda and Mercedes

`items.Where(e=>e.Type=="honda" || e.Type=="mercedes")...`

Now for the second part you can group by multiple columns:

```
items.Where(e=>e.Type=="honda" || e.Type=="mercedes")
     .GroupBy( x => new{x.Type,x.RelatedId})
     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.UniqueId).FirstOrDefault())
     .OrderByDescending(r => r.size)
     .Take(10);
```

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? The code doesn't compile with C# 6 and C# 7. I get an error on the `SelectMany`

Comment: What error? `SelectMany` should support that its not only to flatten collections, it can work as a `Select` too. Try change it for a `Select`

Comment: The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Okay, I will change it, it's more intuitive too, thanks

Comment: thanks @octavioccl , when u specify the group => new {x.Type, x.RelatedId},  .... the type and relatedId have to be the same isnt it? But in my case, they could be different ... for multiple rows with the same RelatedId ...

Comment: Please, post an example. That will allow me to give an accurate answer

Comment: @octavioccl ... sorry ... i updated the question with more details..hope its understandable now ... i also tried your other query .. I get an exception :         The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead. Thank you very much for your help..!

Comment: Oh, are you using EF? I will take a look

Comment: My query doesn't return what you are expecting? The order in the result is the only I can see different

Comment: No, i am getting only the first type honda, it is ignoring other types ...

Comment: Maybe is because the Where condition, you need to make sure the strings you are comparing match with your Type column. Consider apply `Trim().ToLower()` to the strings you are comparing. Remove the `Where` and you will see all the types

Answer (score -1):

> How do i group by so that ONLY honda or mercedes are considered?

```
items.Where(x => x.Type == "honda" || x.Type == "mercedes").GroupBy(etc...)
```